# Networkx node positioning in a complete graph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I want to draw an undirected, weighted, and complete graph with networkx library. My aim is to draw this graph in a way that edge weights represent the distance between nodes.

For example, consider the set of nodes and edges below:

A, B, weight = 5.0

A, C, weight = 50.0

B, C, weight = 0.5

In this case, the distance between A-C is the smallest and B-C is the largest.

I was able to draw this with (after adding edges and nodes to G)

`nx.draw(G, pos=None)`

but, as the number of nodes gets bigger (above 6), inconsistencies occur. What I mean by this is that some nodes get closer although the weight of the edge connecting them is very low.

I assume some of the node positions don't get updated after some point, but I am not sure.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Please post some example code to illustrate your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the layout of the graph, and compute distances based on the layout. Then, you can assign 1/distance as edge weight. Close edges will have stronger connections, edges that are further away will have fainter connections.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.complete_graph(15)

# generate positions
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)

# calculate distances and store as weights
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
edge_updates = {}
edge_widths = []
for (a,b,_) in G.edges(data=True): 
    distance = euclidean(pos[a], pos[b])
    edge_updates[a,b] = {'distance': distance}
    edge_widths.append(1/distance)
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, edge_updates)



nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos)
a = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, edge_cmap=plt.cm.magma, width=edge_widths)
```

[image]